# How to use @Transactional in non spring managed beans?

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I have a bean that was initialized by myself, I want to make the method transactional.

```
class Foo {

  @Transcational
  void method() {
  }
}
```

This is not working because the Foo is not managed by spring, how can I make it work?

I tried to use an `AutowareCapableBeanFactory` to register the `foo` into application context like below:

```
class BeanConfig {

  // programatically initilized
  AutowareCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

  void doSomething() {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    beanFactory.autowireBean(foo);
    foo.method();
  }

}
```

With this approach, `@Autowired` is working in `Foo.class`, but `@Transactional` still not working, but if I use a spring managed bean, the transaction is working, the rollback and database locking all works.

Comment: `will it work if I register the instance in spring context?` - have you tried?

Comment: @jannis I tried to use an `AutowireCapableBeanFactory`, with the `autowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(foo)`, I am assuming this will register the `foo` into the application context, it's not working.

Comment: define `not working`.

Comment: I updated the question, working I mean the rollback, and the database locking all works, which should only work with a transaction, not working means they are not working as they should, for example, rollback for an exception, or waiting for lock if two threads are entering the same code block. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is spring implements @Transactional using dynamic proxy, however you are calling Foo's contructor yourself, therefore, no proxy is involved here

You can solve this by using Spring's TransactionTemplate

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
beanFactory.autowireBean(foo);
context.getBean(TransactionTemplate.class).execute(() -> { 
    foo.method();
});
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. I will say that the execute method needs a `TransactionCallback`.

So you can either do:

```
context.getBean(TransactionTemplate.class).execute(status -> { 
    foo.method();
    return null; // or whatever you need returned
});
```

or if you don't need a return value:

```
context.getBean(TransactionTemplate.class).execute(new 
TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            @Override
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(
                    foo.method();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Foo myFooBean = (Foo) context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()    
    .applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(foo, "myFooBean");
```

This should create the proxy around the Foo instance that handles the `@Transactional` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

@Dapeng's answer worked for me. I will say that the `execute` method needs a `TransactionCallback`.

So you can either do:

```
context.getBean(TransactionTemplate.class).execute(status -> { 
    foo.method();
    return null; // or whatever you need returned
});
```

or if you don't need a return value:

```
context.getBean(TransactionTemplate.class).execute(
    new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
        @Override
        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(
            foo.method();
        }
    });
```