# Using Spring Boots @Transactional when DataSources /JdbcTemplates are not managed by Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

So in My Spring app, we have multiple data sources(each is a different db with different username password) that are constructed as HikariDataSource at runtime and they are not managed by the spring container.
We use a JDBC template that is not managed by Spring container.
My understanding is that @Transactional will not work out of the box in this situation(even if the method I am calling in the Service layer with @Transactional is a Spring managed bean)

How do I

1- Make @Transactional work when my HikariDataSource that is not managed by spring

2- Make @Transactional work with a JdbcTemplate that is not managed by spring

I do not need to maintain a single transaction accross multiple datasources.

The datasources constructed at runtime are very dynamic, there could be 50, there could be 100. I cant hardcode "this is the transaction manager for DataSource 1" etc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57973944/how-to-use-transactional-in-non-spring-managed-beans

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 Repository Configuration and the create separate transaction manager.

Now you can tell @Transactional (name ="xxxTransactionManager) and thus Spring knows which transaction manager to use.

```
XXXRepositoryConfig {

@Bean
    fun xxxEntityManagerFactory(
        factoryBuilder: EntityManagerFactoryBuilder,
        @Qualifier("xxxDataSource") xxxDataSource: DataSource
    ): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean {
        return factoryBuilder
            .dataSource(xxxDataSource)
            .packages("com.xxx.entitites")
            .properties(mapOf("hibernate.default_schema" to "xxxSchema"))
            .build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun xxxTransactionManager(@Qualifier("xxxEntityManagerFactory") xxxEntityManagerFactory: EntityManagerFactory): PlatformTransactionManager {
        val transactionManager = JpaTransactionManager()
        transactionManager.entityManagerFactory = xxxEntityManagerFactory
        transactionManager.entityManagerFactory = xxxEntityManagerFactory
        return transactionManager
    }
}

YYYRepositoryConfig {

@Bean
    fun yyyEntityManagerFactory(
        factoryBuilder: EntityManagerFactoryBuilder,
        @Qualifier("yyyDataSource") yyyDataSource: DataSource
    ): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean {
        return factoryBuilder
            .dataSource(yyyDataSource)
            .packages("com.yyy.entitites")
            .properties(mapOf("hibernate.default_schema" to "yyySchema"))
            .build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun yyyTransactionManager(@Qualifier("yyyEntityManagerFactory") yyyEntityManagerFactory: EntityManagerFactory): PlatformTransactionManager {
        val transactionManager = JpaTransactionManager()
        transactionManager.entityManagerFactory = yyyEntityManagerFactory
        return transactionManager
    }
}
```

Note: sudo code is written in kotlin

Comment: Thanks for the input. I dont think this will work for my use-case. I should have been clearer my apologies. The datasources are very dynamic, there could be 50 and there could be 100. Its not possible for me to hardcode "this is transaction manager for DataSource x". And my DataSources are not spring managed beans

Comment: Then probably think about micro service approach, where you can provide these database interaction as services. I don't this connecting to 50+ datasource from a single application is efficient